# Printf containing i++

Tags: c, printf

In this piece of code:

```
int main()
{
int i=0;
 
       while(i<10)
        printf("%d",i++)
return 0;
}
```

If I am not wrong, the printf will always print the value +1 of i, so the first print will not be 0 but actually 1, am I right?

Comment: You described `++i`  case.

Comment: No, the value of the expression "i++" is the value of i *before* the increment happens.

Comment: Compile, run and observe.

Comment: Looks like a missing  `;`   ? --> "error: expected ';' before 'return'".  Post true code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `x++` evaluates to `x` before incrementing.

```
int x = 5;
printf("%d\n", x++);
// Output: 5
printf("%d", x);
// Output: 6
```

On the other hand, `++x` evaluates to `x + 1`, or `x` after incrementing:

```
int x = 5;
printf("%d\n", ++x);
// Output: 6
printf("%d", x);
// Output: 6
```

Answer (score 3):

You are wrong. The post-increment `i++` is evaluated to the value of `i` *before* incrementing, so what is printed in the first iteration is 0.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile code it is read from left to right like text,
so for example your line 6

```
        printf("%d",i++)
```

would first print the decimal and then add to variable.